# Laravel AJAX: validation always error when sending file via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, validation

so i have a form here which i try to send a file(pdf, doc, docx) to my controller

```
<div class="modal-body">
                {{-- alert if any error exist --}}
                <div class="alert-group-list-education mb-4"></div>
                <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Crew</label>
                        <select class="form-control col-sm-8" name="id_crew" id="id_crew_education">
                            
                        </select>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Instance</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="instance_nm" type="text" class="form-control" id="instance_crew_education" placeholder="Instance" value="{{ old('instance_nm') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label mr-3">Certificate</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="certificate_crew_education" name="scan_certificate">
                            <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose Certificate</label>
                            <div class=" mt-2">
                                <span class="badge badge-primary">
                                    <small id="sh-text4" class="form-text mt-0">PDF,DOCX,DOC</small>
                                </span>
                                <small id="file-certificate-name"></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">More Information</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="more_information" type="text" class="form-control" id="more_info_crew_education" placeholder="More Information" value="{{ old('more_information') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Year In</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="year_in" type="number" class="form-control" id="year_in_crew_education" placeholder="Year In" value="{{ old('year_in') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Year Out</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="year_out" type="number" class="form-control" id="year_out_crew_education" placeholder="Year Out" value="{{ old('year_out') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Status</label>
                        <select class="form-control col-sm-3" name="status" id="status_crew_education">
                            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                            <option value="DE">DE</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
            
                    <div class="form-group row mb-4">
                        <label for="colFormLabel" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Created User</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input name="created_user" type="text" readonly value="{{ auth()->user()->id_login }}" class="form-control" id="created_user_crew_education" placeholder="col-form-label">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="flaticon-cancel-12"></i> Discard</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btn_store_crew_education" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </form>
                
            </div>
```

and for the submit, i wait for $("#btn_store_crew_education") to be clicked, here's my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

........

 $(document).on('click', '#btn_store_crew_education', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        let crew_education_data = {
            id_crew: $('#id_crew_education').val(),
            instance_nm: $('#instance_crew_education').val(),
            scan_certificate: $('#certificate_crew_education').val(),
            more_information: $('#more_info_crew_education').val(),
            year_in: $('#year_in_crew_education').val(),
            year_out: $('#year_out_crew_education').val(),
            status: $('#status_crew_education').val(),
            created_user: $('#created_user_crew_education').val(),
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "crew-education",
            data: crew_education_data,
            success: function (response) {                
                if( response.status == 200 ) {
                    $("#addCrewEducationdModal").modal("hide");
                    Swal.fire(
                        'Success!',
                        `${response.message}`,
                        'success'
                    )
                    fetch_crew_list()
                    add_required_attribute_from_crew_master_modal_input()
                    add_required_attribute_from_crew_master_modal_edit_input()

                    // reseting form
                    $('#id_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#instance_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#certificate_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#more_info_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#year_in_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#year_out_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#status_crew_education').val('')
                    $('#created_user_crew_education').val('')
                } else {
                    $.each(response.errors, function (indexInArray, valueOfElement) { 
                        $('.alert-group-list-education').append(
                            `
                            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                                <strong>${valueOfElement}</strong>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            `
                        )
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

but everytime i try to submit pdf,doc or docx, i always getting validation error from laravel
[image]

here's my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'id_crew' => 'required',
            'instance_nm' => 'required',
            'scan_certificate' => ['mimes:pdf,docx,doc'],
            'more_information' => 'required',
            'year_in' => 'required|numeric',
            'year_out' => 'required|numeric',
            'status' => 'required',
            'created_user' => 'required',
        ]);

        if( $validator->fails() ) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()
            ]);
        }
        else
        {
            $crew_education = new CrewEducation();
            $crew_education->id_crew = $request->id_crew;
            $crew_education->instance_nm = $request->instance_nm;

            if( $request->file('scan_certificate') ) {
                $crew_education->scan_certificate = $request->file('scan_certificate')->store('crew-scan-certificate');
            } 

            $crew_education->more_information = $request->more_information;
            $crew_education->year_in = $request->year_in;
            $crew_education->year_out = $request->year_out;
            $crew_education->status = $request->status;
            $crew_education->created_user = $request->created_user;


            $crew_education->save();

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 200,
                'message' => 'Crew Education Has Been Added'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I don't know why I always getting error from validator.

thank you so much for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [Formdata()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to upload files with jQuery's AJAX handler.

Instead of:

```
let crew_education_data = {
    id_crew: $('#id_crew_education').val(),
    instance_nm: $('#instance_crew_education').val(),
    scan_certificate: $('#certificate_crew_education').val(),
    more_information: $('#more_info_crew_education').val(),
    year_in: $('#year_in_crew_education').val(),
    year_out: $('#year_out_crew_education').val(),
    status: $('#status_crew_education').val(),
    created_user: $('#created_user_crew_education').val(),
}
```

You would do something like this:

```
let formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('id_crew', $('#id_crew_education').val())
formdata.append('instance_nm', $('#instance_crew_education').val())
// Third parameter is to get the file name
formdata.append('scan_certificate', $("#certificate_crew_education")[0].files[0], $('#certificate_crew_education').val().split('\\').pop())
...
```

Then, in your handler

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "crew-education",
    data: formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    ...
})
```

Grain of salt with all of this code as I'm writing it off the cuff, but that should get you pointed in the right direction. As it stands now, the file isn't being uploaded so Laravel's validation is kicking it back.

Comment: thankyou so much, i forget the FormData object for sending file